# Web-app to view Microsoft Excel XLSX spreadsheets without downloading anything

Tags: web-apps, microsoft-excel, text-search, spreadsheet, research

Please recommend a web-app to view Microsoft Excel XLSX spreadsheets without downloading anything.

Looking for something that will run in a web browser (preferably Firefox) on a device that does not have user-writable storage.

Price needs to be gratis, and it is a requirement that no account/login is required.

All the spreadsheets are publicly available via HTTPS, so data privacy is not a concern.

Search functionality is a plus, but the browser's `find` function is likely sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using MS [Excel on web](https://www.office.com/launch/excel?auth=1). You will need to upload the file in OneDrive (part of the offer) and the open it, edit it, search and so on.

The offer is free but need registration.

W/o registration you can try https://accueil.framacalc.org/en For me some of the pages are in French. And I did not found a way to upload excel file

Comment: Thanks Romeo.  The required Microsoft registration is the catch.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, the free cheese is only in the mouse trap....

Comment: LOL. I do enjoy that proverb.  But on the web, so many people have gotten tired of mousetraps that much free cheese has been generously made available for the feasting.  Finding the free cheese and avoiding the MouSetraps (I couldn't resist) is the challenge.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, added another solution